# AlarmManager, alarm is not called when the phone is asleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long schedualed = getNextSchedualTime(context);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, schedualed, makeControlPendingIntent(context));
```

I know to set `RTC_WAKEUP` would run even if phone is sleep. But I want to know when the phone is asleep, would the `RTC` alarm which should be triggered in the sleeping time be delayed to when the phone wake up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC):

> Alarm time in
>   `System.currentTimeMillis()` (wall clock
>   time in UTC). This alarm does not wake
>   the device up; if it goes off while
>   the device is asleep, it will not be
>   delivered until the next time the
>   device wakes up.

So answer to your question: yes, it will be delayed and will not be dropped.